# How to access and rename files using scoped storage within an app targeting Android 11

Tags: java, android, permissions, scoped-storage

I am looking for a way to rename media files in the internal storage of the device from my app. I am told that there are some major changes with permissions in apps that target SDK 30 and there scoped storage is now compulsory. I previously used the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and from what I've read using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE makes the app ineligible for the
Playstore.

So what permission can I use now which can allow me to access and rename media files while staying in bounds of the new privacy changes needed to make my app acceptable for the Playstore while targeting SDK 30.

Also is using the `File` class and `renameTo` method the best way to rename a file?